# Screen scraping over SSL with .NET

Tags: .net, ssl, https, screen-scraping

What solutions exist for screen scraping a site over SSL for use with .NET?

My use case is that I need to login to a partner website (https), navigate through a dynamic hierarchy, and download a zipped file of reports.

I certainly could use other screen scrapers if there are no good viable options in .NET, either though the framework or OSS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps consider [WATIN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) to simulate navigating or [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) if you can find the items yourself and simulate the logic.

Comment: WatiN worked great. I would have shot myself if I had to parse out all of the HTML elements manually.

Answer (score 8):

The gold standard for screen scraping in .NET is the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack).

As far as retrieving pages over HTTPS, try this article:

- [Making Authenticated HTTP Requests from an ASP.NET Page](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020134945/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/102605-1.aspx)

(As mentioned by other answers, you may actually be after *automation* rather than *screen scraping*, in which case you may be better off with [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/), a framework orginally designed for automated web testing, but plenty flexible enough for what you want)

Answer (score 4):

You can certainly do this with HttpWebRequest, but keeping track of the cookies used for logging in may be non-trivial.  I would recommend using [watir](http://wtr.rubyforge.org/) (ruby) or [watin](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) (c#).  Both will handle all of that for you.

From the WatiN website, here is an example:

```
public void SearchForWatiNOnGoogle()
{
 using (IE ie = new IE("http://www.google.com"))
 {
  ie.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");
  ie.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();

  Assert.IsTrue(ie.ContainsText("WatiN"));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've heard of people hosting the browser in their program, and scraping with jQuery.  Seems great to me since jQuery is great for searching the DOM.